# Migrating ckeditor4 to ckeditor5 in Angular

Tags: angular, migration, ckeditor5

I have to migrate a component that uses ckeditor4  to ckeditor5 in Angular 15 app. I have some custom plugins that have been done to enhance the functionality

My requirements:

1. Backward compatibility: Data saved from ckeditor4 should be displayed in ckeditor5 (other way round is not required)
2. Write my custom plugins.

What is the best approach. Any guidance will be helpful